# How to Solve " Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)" Error

Tags: swift3, alamofire, app-transport-security

I have added `AppTransportSecurity` key in `info.plist` , and
added a Subkey called `AllowsArbitraryLoads` as boolean and set its value to YES as like following image.

[image]

But still showing this error:

> {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"},
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://dtcws.azurewebsites.net/ShowImg.aspx?params=dtc_376_0_True_False_22,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.})

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your Info.plist AppTransportSecurity info. EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see the link.

Comment: The NSAllowsArbitraryLoads exception in your Info.plist must have been setup wrong.  The answer you accepted below is if you need domain level exceptions.  The higher level Allows Arbitrary Loads turns it off for **all domains**.  I worry that people will see the accepted answer and get the wrong impression about what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add "Exception Domains" under App Transport Security and specify the domains.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Man ... its Working

Comment: Just a not on this answer - This will eventually require a justification upon app store submission.  As Alec O points out below, if you plan to submit the app to the app store, it is best to switch all communication with your backends to HTTPS in preparation for when Apple starts enforcing the requirements (originally slated to be imposed to all apps submitted after Jan 1, 2017).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a secure connection (`https` instead of `http`) as Apple will begin to reject apps that do not support this in the future, if they haven't begun already. [WWDC 2015 session 703, “Privacy and Your App”](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=703) is a great session to watch if you haven't already.

The good news is that the website you are requesting natively supports `https` so all you have to do is add an `s` to the link.